# Where should I store images (and other files) to be used by my program in Java?

Tags: java, image, imageicon

I'm trying to create a (very) simple GUI program which allows the user to select from different radio buttons to display an image in a JLabel. The code I'm using is this:

```
 JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
 imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/Dog"));
```

My question is, *where* do I put this "images" folder? When I put it in the src *and* the bin folder, the images still didn't load. I ended up trying the following code which worked when I used the bin folder:

```
 imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/Dog")));
```

The problem is, from what I understand the bin folder isn't supposed to be used for these files? Also, I'm pretty sure the images folder I put in there got deleted (which would be a pretty good reason not to use it...).

I'm sending the directory to my professor, so I don't want the file path to work exclusively on my computer.

PS I'm using Eclipse, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put it in the project's folder. Example:

[image: (example image)]

You would put your `images` folder where my "`del_icon`" image is. Just right in the folder.

Comment: Oh. (facepalm) I was convinced that it belongs in one of those folders for some reason... Thanks for that quick response!